# calculate time difference between two rows in mysql having non consecutive ids

Tags: java, mysql

I am stuck in problem. I have a table in mysql database, in which I have attendance record of some employees at particular locations.I want to calculate total login time for an employee on specific date.
Here is the image of my table. Sorry for formatting.

[image]

Comment: Order it by user,location,date,time,status. Then do the time calculations. Is it possible that users login twice at the same location, or don't logout?

Comment: user can login in a day as many times, but he can't login without logout. i.e login and logout are consecutive entries.

Comment: What does '-' mean ? And date/time should be a single entity

Comment: '-' is nothing u can replace it with 'In' or 'Out'. I can not change date/time columns because I have used it in many other functions.TIMEDIFF('START','END') can be used, but I am really stuck, nothing is working.

Comment: Do you wish to do this on sql or on java level?

Comment: Both. But first I want to calculate it in sql, then in java I will handle it.

Answer (score 0):

In sql this is difficult, since you don't have a simple way to match login&logout records together.

For SQL it would go like this (Not tested)

```
select t1.*, t1.date+t1.time as LoginTimeStamp,
 (select top 1 t2.date+t2.time from table t2 
    where 
         t1.user_id=t2.user_id 
     and t1.location_id=t2.location_id
     and t2.date+t2.time > t1.date+t1.time 
    order by t2.date+t2.time asc) 
 as LogoutTimeStamp
 from table t1 where attendance_status='In'
```